# How to insert number 1 in 10 rows in single column and then insert number 2 in next 10 rows and so on?

Tags: excel, vba

Disclaimer: This is a probably easy question coming from a beginner. Please go easy on me.

Currently I am working on a simple experiment where I assign a macro in a button. I want this macro to insert the number 1 in column A, row 1 till 10. Once complete, the number will increase into 2 and will fill in the next 10 rows and so on.

The formula will go on until the range I set for it in the code. As seen below:

```
Sub fill()

    Dim ID

        For c = 1 To 34
            ID = 1
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 1) = ID
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c + 1, 1) = ID
            c = c + 1
        Next c

End Sub
```

At this point it fill the entire cells as 1. For the command to increase the number into 2, I thought of using IF statement to increase it.

```
If c = c * 10 Then
    ID = ID + 1
End If
```

Obviously this didn't work, nor do I know where should I place it in the overall code. Is this the proper way of tackling this issue? Or should I use another method?

Update question:

Now I would like for the code to start on row 3 onwards. Meaning for my for statement I changed it to:

```
Sub fill()
Dim ID
ID = 1
For c = 3 To 34

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 1) = ID
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c + 1, 1) = ID
    c = c + 1
    If (c Mod 10) = 0 Then
        ID = ID + 1
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

However when doing so the number 1 starts at 3 and continues to 10 and then continues onwards. Meaning 1 is created 7 times only. I want to have 1 start from row 3 and repeat to 12, 2 starting from row 13 to 22 and so on. Can this formula still do that?

Comment: You should watch this series [Excel VBA Introduction - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way, just some mathematical tricks.

```
Sub fill()
    For c = 1 To 34
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 1) = (c - 1) \ 10 + 1
    Next c
End Sub
```

Introduce: The \ operator will return the quotient of the two numbers. e.g. 11 \ 4 = 2, and 12 \ 4 = 3

I removed the line `c = c + 1` The variable c controls the For loop, it's dangerous for you to change its value. If there is `c = c + 1` inside the For loop, it will only execute c = 1, 3, 5, 7,... since `Next c` also add 1 on c. I guess that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with an If statement, would be to use Modulo(if you dont know what Modulo does, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation))

The code would look like this:

```
If (c Mod 10) = 0 Then
    ID = ID + 1
End If
```

So it divides by `10`, and every time the rest value is 0 (on 10, 20, 30, etc.)
it would increment ID

You could also use two for loops, but then your limit yould get messed up, so i think the solution above should do. As for where to place it, here:

```
Sub fill()

Dim ID
    ID = 1
    For c = 1 To 34
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c, 1) = ID
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c + 1, 1) = ID
        c = c + 1
        If (c Mod 10) = 0 Then
            ID = ID + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I seem to get a syntax error when I try to use it. Do I need to do some change in settings?

Comment: i must apologise, in VB its not %, but Mod, i am gonna change the answer

Comment: use @sktneer s answer, its way better than mine

Answer (score 0):

You may give this a try...

```
Sub Fill()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, lr As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
lr = 1
For i = 1 To 34
    ws.Range("A" & lr).Resize(10).Value = i
    lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

```
Sub Fill()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, ID As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
ID = 1
For i = 1 To 34
    ws.Range("A" & i).Value = ID
    If i Mod 10 = 0 Then ID = ID + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I intended... The 1 to 34 is the cells that I used (A1 to A34). Meaning that I want A1 till A10 to have number 1, A11 to A20 to have number 2 and so on until the end of the range that is A34. What this code did was copied the number 1 to 34 ten times in ascending order.

Comment: Edited the answer as per your requirement.